# What trait can be used for scalar casts?

Tags: casting, rust, traits, primitive-types

What trait can I restrict `T` to to allow this to compile?

```
fn one<T>() -> T {
    1.0 as _
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", one::<i8>());
}
```

As-is, it gives this error:

```
rustc 1.14.0 (e8a012324 2016-12-16)
error: non-scalar cast: `f64` as `T`
 --> <anon>:2:5
  |
2 |     1.0 as _
  |     ^^^^^^^^
```

A good solution would be a trait that restricts `T` to primitive numeric types (`i8`, `f64`, etc.). I found [`std::num::Primitive`](http://aturon.github.io/stability-dashboard/std/num/trait.Primitive.html) but it's experimental apparently and the nightly compiler couldn't find it anyway.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29025811/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/30942408/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/29184358/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/30057726/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/30044026/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/21073709/155423; http://stackoverflow.com/q/37296351/155423; etc.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Lots of similar questions (maybe an opportunity to improve the book!). The most helpful answer I think it [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29032520/265521).

Answer (score 2):

There is a crate called [num](https://crates.io/crates/num) that provides some traits like the one you mention. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.36/num/). In your particular case, it seems that you should be able to use the [`One`](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.36/num/trait.One.html) trait. This trait is, however, very limited because it only provides one function:

```
pub trait One: Mul<Self, Output=Self> {
    fn one() -> Self;
}
```

Depending on what you are trying to do, you are probably better off using the [`Num`](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.36/num/trait.Num.html) trait, which is a subtrait of `Zero<Output=Self> + One<Output=Self> + Add<Self> + Sub<Self, Output=Self> + Mul<Self> + Div<Self, Output=Self> + Rem<Self, Output=Self> + PartialEq<Self>`.

Both traits are implemented for the primitive numerical types (`usize`, `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `isize`, `i8`, `i16`, `i32`, `i64`, `f32`, `f64`). Note, however, that they are also implemented for some types that are defined in the library (`BigInt`, `BigUint`, `Ratio`, `Complex`).

Answer (score 2):

Answering the question you asked:

> What trait can be used for scalar casts?

None. Traits only define methods and associated types. Scalar casts are built into the language and are not open for extension.

[aochagavia has answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41314890/155423) "how do I solve this problem".

Comment: Aren't some traits like `Sync` and `Copy` 'magic'? If so I don't think it is unreasonable to expect a magic `Primitive` trait.